# Hook.io on Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, hook.io

I am creating a Node.js app on Heroku and have run into an issue. I am trying to use [Hook.io](https://github.com/hookio/hook.io) in my application but am getting a "Bad Bind" error from Heroku because Hook uses port 5000. Does anyone know of a way around this, maybe by somehow telling Heroku I need another port for Hook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe requires hook.io have access to bind to multiple TCP ports. I'm not sure how much success you will find on Heroku with this.

You'll also note that `hook.io-webserver` has been deprecated see: https://github.com/hookio/webserver in favor of the latest core hook.io API which allows for native HTTP and Websocket support for hooks.

For new HTTP webserver API, see: https://github.com/hookio/hook.io/blob/master/examples/webserver/server.js

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid I was going to have trouble getting this to work on Heroku. I will look at those links, but I will probably just end up building it without Hook.io. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hook.io is defaulting to port 5000, but on Heroku, you need to use the port Heroku dynamically assigns your app.

```
var hook = hookio.createHook({
  hook-port: process.env.PORT || 5000
});
```

[Here](https://github.com/hookio/hook.io/wiki/Documentation%3a-Configuration) are the configs available for Hook.io.

Comment: Yes, but I am also running a webserver and I can't run both on the same port; So I guess what I really need to know is if there is a way around this, like getting a second port assigned to my app on Heroku so I can run both the webserver and Hook.io.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're using Hook.io for?

Comment: I am trying to run my http server and most of the app in one hook and separating out a couple of heavier tasks into other hooks to keep from blocking the main process. I know this can be done in other ways (such as using fork), but I was hoping I could get it working with Hook.io